# How to Block date & time if others user already chose that date & time

Tags: php, date, time, system

Right now i am developing a booking vehicle system using html,php,sql. I dont know how to describe my question but let me give a situation example.

user 1: want to book vehicle on 11 may 2017 @ 0930 and the admin already approved this user form.

user 2: want to book vehicle at the same date & time as user 1 and here is the problem. How to block others user from proceed the booking if that date & time already have a user?

Hope you guys can help me, thank you!

this is my coding for date & time. it is in form for user to book and i want to make it once they click submit if that date & time already booked will pop up msg like 'already booked'.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tcal.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tcal.js"></script> 

    <script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Permohonan anda akan diproses. Sila jangan tutup paparan sehingga selesai.");
}
</script>

    <form action="processform.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <table width="100%"  align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <br> 

    <br>
    <tr bgcolor="#e2e8ef">
    <td colspan="3" class="font12bold">&nbsp; BUTIRAN PERJALANAN</td>
    </tr>

            <tr class="font12">
            <td>&nbsp; Date to Depart <b class="icon_required" style="color:#FF0000">*</b></td>
            <td align="center">:</td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="departDate" class="tcal" value="" />
            <font class="font12gray">[dd-mm-yyyy]</font></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="font12">
            <td>&nbsp; Time to Depart <b class="icon_required" style="color:#FF0000">*</b></td>
            <td align="center">:</td>
            <td>
            <select name="timeDepart">
            <option value="-">-Sila Pilih-</option>
            <option value="01:00" >1:00</option>
            <option value="01:30" >1:30</option>
            <option value="02:00" >2:00</option>
            <option value="02:30" >2:30</option>
            <option value="03:00" >3:00</option>
            <option value="03:30" >3:30</option>
            <option value="04:00" >4:00</option>
            <option value="04:30" >4:30</option>
            <option value="05:00" >5:00</option>
            <option value="05:30" >5:30</option>
            <option value="06:00" >6:00</option>
            <option value="06:30" >6:30</option>
            <option value="07:00" >7:00</option>
            <option value="07:30" >7:30</option>
            <option value="08:00" >8:00</option>
            <option value="08:30" >8:30</option>
            <option value="09:00" >9:00</option>
            <option value="09:30" >9:30</option>
            <option value="10:00" >10:00</option>
            <option value="10:30" >10:30</option>
            <option value="11:00" >11:00</option>
            <option value="11:30" >11:30</option>
            <option value="12:00" >12:00</option>
            <option value="12:30" >12:30</option>
            </select>
            <select name="waktuDepart">
            <option value="" > - </option>
            <option value="Pagi" > Pagi</option>
            <option value="Tengahari" >Tengahari</option>
            <option value="Petang" >Petang</option>
            <option value="Malam" >Malam</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="font12">
            <td>&nbsp; Date to Return <b class="icon_required" style="color:#FF0000">*</b></td>
            <td align="center">:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="returnDate" class="tcal" value="" />
            <font class="font12gray">[dd-mm-yyyy]</font></td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="font12">
            <td>&nbsp; Time to Return <b class="icon_required" style="color:#FF0000">*</b></td>
            <td align="center">:</td>
            <td><select name="returnTime">
            <option value="-">-Sila Pilih-</option>
            <option value="01:00" >1:00</option>
            <option value="01:30" >1:30</option>
            <option value="02:00" >2:00</option>
            <option value="02:30" >2:30</option>
            <option value="03:00" >3:00</option>
            <option value="03:30" >3:30</option>
            <option value="04:00" >4:00</option>
            <option value="04:30" >4:30</option>
            <option value="05:00" >5:00</option>
            <option value="05:30" >5:30</option>
            <option value="06:00" >6:00</option>
            <option value="06:30" >6:30</option>
            <option value="07:00" >7:00</option>
            <option value="07:30" >7:30</option>
            <option value="08:00" >8:00</option>
            <option value="08:30" >8:30</option>
            <option value="09:00" >9:00</option>
            <option value="09:30" >9:30</option>
            <option value="10:00" >10:00</option>
            <option value="10:30" >10:30</option>
            <option value="11:00" >11:00</option>
            <option value="11:30" >11:30</option>
            <option value="12:00" >12:00</option>
            <option value="12:30" >12:30</option>
            </select>
            <select name="waktuReturn">
            <option value="" >- </option>
            <option value="Pagi" >Pagi</option>
            <option value="Tengahari" >Tengahari</option>
            <option value="Petang" >Petang</option>
            <option value="Malam" >Malam</option>
            </select>
            </td>
            </tr>

            </table>
            <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Hantar" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="myFunction()"> &nbsp; [ <a href="index.php">kembali</a> ]<br></center>

        </td></tr></table>
        </form>
```

Comment: IF first user book vehicle you need to save this date time into DB. When second user try to book again the vehicle at same date time then check the value from db and show some message to 2nd user **"Already book or some thing like"**

Comment: tq for the response but can you please show me the code.

Comment: is this correct? IF (date=='$date' & time=='$time') {

echo "The vehicle already booked. Please choose other date & time";

}

Comment: Show your code, its not right.

Comment: See this. https://jsfiddle.net/trungkim2201/cdj4njre/

Comment: Provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: i already edit the post added the coding